# How can I declare a table without primary key?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL Query Browser.

I have tried this code:

```
CREATE TABLE  `something`.`payment_something` (
    `firstName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `inputEmail` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    `genderRadios` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `monthh` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `dayy` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `yearr` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `postalAddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `phoneNumber` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `ZipCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `CreditCard` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `expireMonth` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `expireYear` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `Institution` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    `textinput` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `radios` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=greek;
```

of course it shows error in the `PRIMARY KEY` line. Any idea?

**EDIT Better solution**

```
CREATE TABLE  `something`.`payment_something` (
    `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `inputEmail` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    `genderRadios` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `monthh` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `dayy` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `yearr` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `postalAddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `phoneNumber` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `ZipCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `CreditCard` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `expireMonth` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `expireYear` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `Institution` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    `textinput` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `radios` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=greek;
```

It shows wrong in the `PRIMARY KEY` line why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply exclude the problematic line:

```
PRIMARY KEY ()
```

You don't need to have that line, if you are not actually defining a key.  In your example, you will also have to remove the comma directly preceding this line, of course.

UPDATE:

In your updated example, just take the `''` off of `'id'` when you declare it.  Use the backtick (`), instead of the apostrophe:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: ok thank you! but i dedided to add a auto increment primary key. could you please solve the error that i have again. i edited my post